# How to change view pager height depending on content?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-tabs

I have a layout contained inside a ScrollView. The layout contains some views and then I have a tab layout and a view pager. I want the view pager to change its height depending on which tab I'm on as I have more content on tab 2 and 3 than on tab 1. Right now the view pager has the height of the first tab opened, so when I switch tabs the view pager doesn't expand.

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ConstraintLayout...>
              <EditText ...>

              ...

              <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_gray"
                            app:tabBackground="@drawable/search_tab_bar"
                            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/size_0"
                            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
                            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/SearchTabLayoutTextAppearance"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_view"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
         </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have tried using scrollview.invalidate() and scrollview.requestLayout() in order to have the scrollview refresh when I switch tabs, however it did not work.